# Redirect to other page, then previous, if validation fails

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have a search page with a submit form, when the user submits is goes to a controller method. In that method I validate the fields, like so:

```
$this->validate($request, [
            'title'         => 'alpha',
            'description'   => 'alpha',
        ]);
```

Is is possible to redirect to a other page, then the previous submit form,
if the validation fails?

Comment: yes its possible by using route name .

Comment: Can you give a example with providing the route name, if the validation fails?

Answer (score 4):

You can manually create a validator to have more control

```
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'title' => 'required|unique:posts|max:255',
        'body' => 'required',
    ]);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return redirect('post/create')
                    ->withErrors($validator)
                    ->withInput();
    }
```

Comment: You can even use **FormRequest** and override the response function to redirect someplace else. [Here is the link](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.2/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/FormRequest.php)